# Android : Is there anyway to get battery capacity of a device in mah?

Tags: android, battery

I want to get battery capacity of a device to do some battery consumption computation, is it possible to get it somehow? For instance, battery capacity for Samsung Galaxy Note 2 is 3100 mah. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Got it! Couldn't find anything straight in SDK but can be done using reflection.

Here is the working code :-

```
public void getBatteryCapacity() {
    Object mPowerProfile_ = null;

    final String POWER_PROFILE_CLASS = "com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile";

    try {
        mPowerProfile_ = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    try {
        double batteryCapacity = (Double) Class
                .forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getMethod("getAveragePower", java.lang.String.class)
                .invoke(mPowerProfile_, "battery.capacity");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, batteryCapacity + " mah",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: @AakashGandhi, It does work for me. So far it's been working on all Android versions I have tested.