# How to get the current battery capacity on Android?

Tags: android, battery, capacity

I want to get the current battery capacity in mAh of my android phone.
Until now, I haven't found any solution to fix this.
My solution is, to get the last  [capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193388/android-get-battery-current-capacity-in-ma-and-total-capacity-of-battery-in-mah) and multiply this value with the current battery [level](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html).
But this is very unexactly. Is there any oher possibility for this issue?

Comment: Could this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22243511/1329901

Comment: The same solution I had linked in my original post. It shows only the maximum the the battery capacity but not the current value.