# How to calculate total capacity of a battery

Tags: java, android, hardware, battery

I have all information about battery. Now I just need an one more information. What is the total capacity of battery? Suppose I am using Samsung A3. The total capacity of battery for Samsung A3 is 1900 mAh . Now I need this information pragmatically. It will be difference for difference device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : Is there anyway to get battery capacity of a device in mah?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243461/android-is-there-anyway-to-get-battery-capacity-of-a-device-in-mah)

Answer (score -1):

The capacity of a battery is how many amps it can supply an hour long. So when it can supply 1A for an hour, and then it's empty, the capacity is 1Ah, 1000mAh.

So, when you have how many amps it's supplying, and for how long it can do that, you have to multiply the amps (A/mA) and the time (hours) to get the capacity.

Comment: If possible help me with code. I am working in android studio