# Android get battery current capacity in mA and total capacity of battery in mAh

Tags: android, android-intent

Android Get Battery total capacity in mAh and Current Battery Capacity in mA.

Comment: object mPowerProfile_ = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS).getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
batteryCapacity = (Double) Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
.getMethod("getAveragePower", java.lang.String.class).invoke(mPowerProfile_, "battery.capacity");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243461/android-is-there-anyway-to-get-battery-capacity-of-a-device-in-mah

Comment: I am able to get total capacity of battery in mAh but i want to get battery discharge time so now i want to know how i can get battery current capacity in mA.

Comment: how did you calculate battery discharge time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this..

```
    public void getBatteryCapacity() {
    Object mPowerProfile_ = null;

    final String POWER_PROFILE_CLASS = "com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile";

    try {
        mPowerProfile_ = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    try {
        double batteryCapacity = (Double) Class
                .forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
                .getMethod("getAveragePower", java.lang.String.class)
                .invoke(mPowerProfile_, "battery.capacity");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, batteryCapacity + " mah",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Tested this method on Android versions Lollipop to Oreo - it's not broken yet. Getting correct battery capacity values.

Comment: This is not working for me in Android L, 
I'm checking in Vivo y21 device which contains 1900mAh battery, but I'm getting 3900mAh

Comment: Those values are hard-coded by manufacturer. Hence some device just report crap information. There is another method (standard API) but it never returns the same value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998034/total-battery-capacity-in-mah-of-device-programmatically